# Azure Web Service and "Add Identity Provider": Create new app registration is disabled

Tags: azure, web-services, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I want to implement secure app auth follow on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service

When I try to add an identity provider, I see, that "Create new app registration" is disabled

[image]

why so and how to implement it?
Thank you!

Comment: Is this for government cloud by chance? There's a note here that it's not available for government

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have tried to add authentication by following the given document.
- `Create new app registration` is enabled for me.

[image]

- As per [scottwtang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18748575/scottwtang) comment,
  in the [Configure Azure AD authentication for your App Service application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad), it clearly says that -  the option to `create a new registration` is not available for government clouds.
- In such cases, we need to  [define a registration separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#advanced).